# How can I change the default output, input tensor names in tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

Tensorflow object detection API by default has output tensor names **num_detections** , **detection_boxes**, **detection_scores** and **detection_classes** . How can I change these default names ? Unfortunately an inference platform that I am testing does not accept tensor names with underscores.
Thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output tensor names are defined in the "meta_architectures" python files in the object detection project which can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py).
You could try to adjust/convert the naming of the output tensors there for when you are doing the model export for inference but I haven't tried this myself.